# What can F# offer for managing nondeterminism?

Tags: f#, purely-functional

Using non-deterministic functions is unavoidable in applications that talk to the real world. Making a clear separation between deterministic and non-deterministic is important.

Haskell has the IO monad that sets the impure context by looking at which we know that everything outside of it is pure. Which is nice, if you ask me, when it comes to unit testing one can tell which part of their code is ultimately testable and which is not.

I could not find anything that allows separating the two in F#. Does it mean there is just no way to do that?

Comment: Although not a "bad" question, it's likely better suited to the CS stack.

Comment: You can model non-determinism using lists so it is not necessarily about impurity. IO is used to model computations with side-effects, and while you could create your own IO implementation in F#, it probably wouldn't be much use since any function can potentially have side-effects.

Comment: @Lee, forgive my ignorance, how can lists help modeling non-determinism?

Comment: @bonomo - You use the list to contain all the possible values for some non-deterministic choice.

Comment: You could wrap everything nondeterministic in a computation expression.  That sounds like a lot of work to me, but still possible...

Comment: @mydogisbox, a homemade computation expression and a special mindset don't prevent unintended use of non-deterministic functions elsewhere, so why bother?

Comment: I agree, but you didn't specify that you wanted it enforced by the compiler.  You just said you wanted a clear separation.  As @stonemetal notes, F# isn't a pure functional language so enforcing with the compiler isn't possible.

Comment: @mydogisbox, well to me being clear primarily means being consistent, if it's not consistent then how clear is it? I believe only restrictive mechanisms like special classes/types/operators + compiler can do this. What you have suggested can be done just by putting some discipline on how you name functions. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 5):

The distinction between deterministic and non-deterministic function is not captured by the F# type system, but a typical F# system that needs to deal with non-determinism would use some structure (or "design pattern") that clearly separates the two.

- If your core model is some computation that does not interact with the world (you only need to collect inputs and run the computation), then you can write most of your code as functional transformations on immutable data structures and then invoke these from some "main" I/O loop.
- If you're writing some highly interactive or reactive application then you can use F# agents (here is [an introductory article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/139804/an-introduction-to-f-agents/)) and structure your application so that the non-determinism is safely contained in individual agents (see [more about agent-based architectures](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/140677/writing-concurrent-applications-using-f-agents/))

Answer (score 2):

F# is based on OCaml, and much like OCaml it isn't pure FP.  I don't believe there is away to accomplish your goal in either language.

Answer (score 0):

One way to manage it could be in making up a nominal type that would represent the notion of the real world and make sure each non-deterministic function takes its singleton as a parameter. This way all dependent functions would have to pass it on along the line. This makes a strong distinction between the two at a cost of some discipline and a bit of extra typing. Good thing about this approach is that it can verified by the compiler given necessary conditions are met.